# Why can't I reverse an iterator twice to get the last two numbers of a vector?

Tags: functional-programming, rust, iterator

I want to take the last two numbers of a vector. Why can't I reverse the iterator twice?

```
fn main() {
    let double_reversed = &vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        .into_iter()
        .rev()
        .take(2)
        .rev()
        .collect();

    println!("{}", double_reversed); // expected 8, 9
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=78d8ffb96270f1e65305fff84d980f6b)

The error messages are:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::iter::Take<std::iter::Rev<std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>>>: std::iter::DoubleEndedIterator` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:6:10
  |
6 |         .rev()
  |          ^^^ the trait `std::iter::DoubleEndedIterator` is not implemented for `std::iter::Take<std::iter::Rev<std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>>>`

error[E0599]: no method named `collect` found for type `std::iter::Rev<std::iter::Take<std::iter::Rev<std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>>>>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:7:10
  |
7 |         .collect();
  |          ^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: the method `collect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `std::iter::Rev<std::iter::Take<std::iter::Rev<std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>>>> : std::iter::Iterator`
          `&mut std::iter::Rev<std::iter::Take<std::iter::Rev<std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>>>> : std::iter::Iterator`
```

Comment: I think it says that the iterator returned by `.take(2)` (`std::iter::Take<std::iter::Rev<std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>>>`) cannot be reversed because it does not support the `std::iter::DoubleEndedIterator` trait that defines the `rev` method

Comment: Shouldn't the comment on the last line be `expected 8, 9`?

Comment: @Jmb Thanks. You're right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the compiler tells you (cleaned up):

> the trait bound `Take<...>: DoubleEndedIterator` is not satisfied

[`Iterator::Rev`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev) is only implemented when the underlying type implements `DoubleEndedIterator`:

```
fn rev(self) -> Rev<Self>
where
    Self: DoubleEndedIterator,
```

[`Take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Take.html) does not implement `DoubleEndedIterator`, so you cannot call `rev` on it.

---

I'd just slice it:

```
let items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let last_2 = &items[items.len() - 2..];
assert_eq!(last_2, [8, 9]);
```